# Can't add segments to plane

Tags: modeling

I have been trying to add segments to a plane, and I am not given the option. I have tried typing F6 or T before adding it, and I am still not given the option to add more segments. This appears to be the case with other objects as well. What am I doing wrong? I am new to blender, so I can imagine the answer is very simple.

[image: Not given the option to add segments, even when pressing F6 or T prior to adding the object.]

Comment: If you mean subdivide or extrude or else, you need to select your object and go in Edit mode (Tab)

Comment: Hi. What has led you to believe that there should be an option appearing to add more segments when adding planes?

Answer (score 0):

I think all other 3d applications have ability to add more segments for basic primitives. I don't think it's unjustified to assume that would be the case in Blender as well.
Unfortunately I don't have good solution for this, nor any other primitives if you have already created it.
However if you create a Grid it's plane with segment options when you create it. When creating a grid look left lower corner and you'll find this.

[image]

But only when creating it. After clicking somewhere it's gone forever.

Comment: It's not gone forever! There is one more chance. You can press F9 to bring it back the lost menu!

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities for similar effects:

1. You have a plane
2. Press TAB to enter edit mode
3. Press Ctrl+R to make a [Loop Cut](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/loop.html)
4. Use mouse scroll wheel to adjust number of cuts
5. Left click to apply number of cuts
6. Right click to apply the loop cuts in perfect center of plane
7. Repeat is second direction

[image: add segments using loop cout]

1. You have a plane
2. Press TAB to enter edit mode
3. Press A to select everything
4. Right click to show menu
5. Use "Subdivide" Tool

[image: 3. Press A to select everything]